# How to read and write the file using c#

Tags: c#

I want to read the file from the local system and i want to write the file again. I am writing  code like:

```
   byte[] destination = new byte[file.ContentLength];
   FileInfo fil = new FileInfo(@"d:\\Projects\\file");
     if (!fil.Exists)
       {
         using (Stream sw = fil.OpenWrite())
            {
              sw.Write(destination, 0, file.ContentLength);
              sw.Close();
            }
      }
```

I am able to download the file but i am not able to read the file that is downloaded. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How does `asp.net-mvc` fit into this?

Comment: You should provide more info about the file type, how you get the path(comppath) and how you download the file.

Comment: Can we see how you are trying to read the file?

Comment: the comppath is the file that should be downloded. I have updated the question

Comment: @TiesonT. Define "local"? i didn't get you.

Comment: "Local" as in "on the server" or "local" as in "on the client" - your partial code above does not show how/where `file` is created.

Comment: Retagged to remove mvc.

Comment: @TiesonT. I think the problem is with the destination. It is getting 0 bytes

Comment: I don't quite understand the use of the word "download" here. That is normally used in client-server scenarios, but we're only talking about local files here. Am I missing something?

Comment: @stakx I mean the file will be creating in that particular folder

Comment: Off-topic: You do not need to escape a backslash in a `@""` string literal. Just write `@"C:\Foo\bar.ext"`... or `"C:\\Foo\\Bar.ext"`.

Answer (score 0):

> comppath + file.FileName

First, try to avoid creating file path like this. Use System.IO.Path.Combine(comppath,file.FileName) instead.

Now debug your app and check where the downloaded file is saved. Check your save and read path are same or not. If you can write file somewhere then you can also read from the same location unless some weird rules are not applied which provide write only access to you.

Comment: I have tried like what you said. But if i open the file it is saying like there is some problem with the content.

Comment: @Naidu _"it is saying like there is some problem with the content"_ - show the exact exception message.

Comment: I have selected the doc file and write the same doc file to another folder using the above code. Then when i am opening the newly created doc file. it is showing exception: The office xml file companies controller cannot be because there are problems with the contents.